# Discussing answer quoted from a different website

Tags: discussion

I have got a detailed explanation for a complex mathematical problem taken from a different site. Can I refer it here and ask whether any more methods are there to solve the same problem. Is this allowed as per rules for this community.

Comment: It would be best if you can provide enough context so that people don't *have* to leave MSE to understand your question (although of course you *should* link to the other content). That's really the only danger here, that the question might not be "self-contained" enough. Your question certainly sounds valid and mathematical.

Comment: thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the answer should relate to the topic a lot, but still be able to hold its own weight. However, you should still include the link to the other website.